# Neo4j query not making use of indexes

Tags: neo4j

I have several types of node labels (Asset1, Asset2, etc), all of which can be connected to any of the others; each asset has different fields but all have in common an `id` field. I am saving this data in CSV files to be loaded in Neo4j: node data is saved in asset1.csv, asset2.csv, etc, while relationship data is saved in a connection.csv file with the following header: `asset_1_id`, `asset_1_type`, `asset_2_id`, `asset_2_type`.

Loading the nodes is easy:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///assetN.csv' AS row
CREATE (n:AssetN {
  id: row.id,
  // other fields for AssetN
})
```

Before loading the nodes, I define separate indexes for each asset type:

```
CREATE INDEX assetN_id IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:AssetN) ON (n.id);
```

Loading the relationships is a bit trickier, because my first solution never terminates:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///connection.csv' AS row
MATCH (asset1 { id: row.asset_1_id })
MATCH (asset2 { id: row.asset_2_id }) 
    
MERGE (asset1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(asset2)
```

It seems that if I don't specify the label type, Neo4j does not look for an index in case it exists. I understand sometimes it may not exist (e.g. let's say there is another asset type without that index defined), but I would expect it to try and then default to a full scan otherwise.

So my second solution is to try and use APOC to read the labels dynamically from the CSV file:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///connection.csv' AS row
CALL apoc.merge.node([row.asset_1_type], { mrid: row.asset_1_id }) YIELD node as asset1
CALL apoc.merge.node([row.asset_2_type], { mrid: row.asset_2_id }) YIELD node as asset2   
 
MERGE (asset1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(asset2)
```

But this never terminates either, as it still does not seem to use the indexes.

The only solution I found so far that actually works is defining an additional label for each asset type (called Asset), defining a single index on Asset and then loading the relationship data:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///connection.csv' AS row
MATCH (asset1:Asset { id: row.asset_1_id })
MATCH (asset2:Asset { id: row.asset_2_id }) 
    
MERGE (asset1)-[:CONNECTED_TO]-(asset2)
```

This is extremely quick because it actually uses the index, but I don't like having to add a label to each node just to optimise loading the data.

Are there other solutions I am not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j does not require nodes to have consistent labeling, so every node can have any number of labels (including 0).

Now, let's suppose the Cypher execution planner was "super-smart" and *could* automatically use indexes if you did not specify any labels. In that case, the planner would have to test *every matching node* for its labels, and then try to determine a single coherent plan that used a combination of indexes involving those labels to minimize execution time.

Since this requires scanning all matching nodes just to come up with the execution plan, we have swamped any speedup we would get by executing the resulting plan with indexes.

So, a "super-smart" Cypher planner would be too slow to be of any use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that does make sense. Any idea why the version with apoc.merge.node does not seem to make use of the indexes though? I should expect that to work, but the procedure (which I am calling in transactions of 10k rows) grinds to a halt after about 70k/80k relationships.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Cypher does not support dynamic labels. But the apoc library does: See

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.merge/apoc.merge.node/